# how to open index.php instead of index.html on nginx server?

Tags: nginx

Nginx server open index.html by default how to change that to index.php ?
when i type my server ip it opens index.html instead of index.php 
there is no index.html file on server but there is index.php file .

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [index](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html):

```
location / {
  index index.php index.html;
}
```

Note that `index.php` is the first.

Comment: where to add this ?

Comment: Into `nginx.conf`, in `http` or `server` (or `location`) section. See more the documentation!